# Restrict Search Domain

Tags: php, search, restrict

I have a data set that I'm searching for certain [IPA symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). I'd like to restrict the search domain in accordance with the value of $where shown in the code below, but don't know how. *EDIT: Where $where is "onset" "nucleui" and "coda."* **Does anyone know how to restrict the search domain?** (The code below is in php but the file is linked to an HTML file that a person could use to search for the IPA symbols in the data set.) *EDIT: See added code at bottom.*

```
//set up variables
$words = $table[0]; //row 1 of table
$target = $table[1]; //row 2
$indices = array(); //used to store column numbers
$IPAstr = $_POST["ipa"];
$where = $_POST["where"];

//Find $IPAstr in $target
for($i=1; $i<count($target); $i++)
{
    if (mb_strpos($target[$i],$IPAstr) !== false)
        $indices[] = $i;        
}

//List realizations & count frequency
for($i=0; $i<count($indices); $i++)
{
    $index = $indices[$i];
    $ipalist = array();
    echo "<table border=1><tr><td>".$target[$index]." in " . $words[$index]."</td></tr><td>";
    //output each speaker and count frequency
    for ($j=2; $j<count($table); $j++) {
        echo ($j-1).": ".$table[$j][$index]."<br>";
        $ipalist[$table[$j][$index]]++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    //output frequency list
    foreach($ipalist as $ipa=>$fre)
        echo "$ipa: $fre<br>";
    echo "</td></tr></table>";
}

//Code to help search for "onset" "nuclei" and "coda"
//list onsets only
echo "Onsets only<br>";
for($col=0; $col<count($table[0]); $col++) {
    $s = $table[0][$col];
    if (whichSyllPart($s) == 'o') echo "$s ";   
}

//list nuclei only
echo "Nuclei only<br>";
for($col=0; $col<count($table[0]); $col++) {
    $s = $table[0][$col];
    if (whichSyllPart($s) == 'n') echo "$s ";   
}

//list codas only
echo "Codas only<br>";
for($col=0; $col<count($table[0]); $col++) {
    $s = $table[0][$col];
    if (whichSyllPart($s) == 'c') echo "$s ";   
}
```

Comment: This is probably one of the most well documented pieces of code I've ever seen.  Why does it look like a student project?

Comment: Are we not all students? ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to restrict the search domain you need to enter the following code as part of the "//Find $IPAstr in $target" section of the code.

```
//Find $IPAstr in $target
for($i=1; $i<count($target); $i++)
{
    if ($where == whichSyllPart($words[$i])){
        if (mb_strpos($target[$i],$IPAstr) !== false)
            $indices[] = $i;
    }
    else if ($where == "everywhere"){
        if (mb_strpos($target[$i],$IPAstr) !== false)
            $indices[] = $i;
    }
}
```

For this to run you need a function whichSyllPart()

```
function whichSyllPart($sy)
{
    $pt = $sy[strlen($sy)-1];
    return($pt);
}
```

This adds an if/else if statement including the whichSyllPart() function that restricts the search according to the value of $where.